# 3.5mm Stereo output to 3.5mm mic input crossover

Tags: audio, signal

I have two devices, each with two 3.5mm jacks for the usual audio out / in.  I need a way to cross-over between the two, such that the stereo output of one, goes to the mic input of the other.  I have looked into and considered other options and (unfortunately), this is the best option for this project.  The devices aren't terribly smart (one has no accessible software component, and one is a knock-off RPi).  A software solution wont work, I need a hardware implementation.  I have looked around and found several related issues, but I haven't found an actual solution anywhere that works.  I did rig up a cross-over cable myself which does work, but barely, and with great audio issues.  This seems like it shouldn't be that difficult, but the mic works with much lower voltage than the stereo out, so feeding it directly across isn't a viable / good solution.

Any help is warmly welcomed, or something as simple as a usb audio card that can do it (one of the devices is a RPi type board).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your recording device is like the RPI, a linux based system with usb inputs, Any generic usb sound card with a stereo/line level **in** would work. About 2 bucks on ebay with china shipping. Built-in support in 99% of Linux Distros.

If not, see [Circuit to Convert Line Level to Mic Level](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29564/circuit-to-convert-line-level-to-mic-level) for a way to convert **Line Level** (which most common outputs are) to Mic Level signals. A pair of resistors and maybe a cap. Keep in mind most Mic inputs on pcs and similar consumer hardware are MONO, not Stereo.

Also a premade **Patch Cable** (also called an Aux cable, check the dollar store) would likely work better than your handmade one.

Comment: A USB card with line-in would work perfectly... except that I still need to go down to mic-level for the return line.  (Part of) the reason my cable was so poor, is that I was trying to merge the stereo lines and had a single pot for messing with the level.  I will buy proper aux cables (I should have thought of that).  Ultimately, the link is what I needed, thanks :)